# request to the same parse method

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I don't understand how requests works. I don't know why `scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse2)` doesn't work as I thought. Pitem is response of this request, but I  i have `KeyError: 'pitem'` I don't know why the first `request` works, but `request2` not

**MY CODE:**

> spider.py

```
...
def parse(self, response):
  ...
  request = scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse2)
  request.meta['item'] = item
  yield request
  ...
def parse2(self, response)
   item = response.meta['item']
   pitem = response.meta['pitem']
   ...
   pitem['field'].append(self.whatever)
   if next_page is not None:
       request2 = scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse2)
       request2.meta['pitem'] = item
       yield request2
   else:
       yield pitem

   self.whatever = []
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  request = scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse2)
  request.meta['item'] = item
  yield request
```

This does define a meta variable with the name `item` but not with `pitem`. So when you call function `parse2` and say `pitem = response.meta['pitem']` it is unable to find `pitem` in the request meta data.

One possible solution might be to use `pitem = response.meta.get('pitem')` which will return a `None` value if it's unable to find `pitem` but that depends very much on your usecase.